# IIS 7.5 server redirecting to Default Web Site

Tags: iis

My IIS seems to redirect to Default Web Site when I just type in my site's URL without specifying the actual page (e.g. index.cfm (I run ColdFusion 10)), but when I specify the actual page it works fine. I've set up the Default Document with index.cfm but it just doesn't seem to want to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is now fixed. We noticed that the Handler Mappings of Coldfusion weren't inherited in our site, when we reverted to parent it added them and the problem was solved.